# Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $deal ]]

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Hola tengo el siguiente error:

> Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $deal ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\Registeractivity\DetailRegisteractivities (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\resources\views\registeractivity\detail.blade.php)

En mi controlar tengo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Registeractivity;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\registeractivity\DetailRegisteractivity;

class DetailRegisteractivities extends Component
{

    public $deal;

    public function mount($deal)
    {
        $this->deal = $deal;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.registeractivity.detail-registeractivities');
    }
}
```

En mi ruta:

```
 Route::get('registeractivity/detail/{deal}', [RegisteractivityController::class, 'detail'])->name('registeractivity.detail')->middleware('translate');
```

Y finalmente:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold leading-tight text-gray-800">
            {{ __('Create Activity') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card">
            @livewire('registeractivity.detail-registeractivities')
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout
```

Ya intente de muchas maneras pero ninguna me da.

¿Alguien me pudiera ayudar? Gracias.

---

Haciendo pruebas segun la documentacion realice este

en el controlador puse

```
public $user;

    public function mount(User $user)
    {
        $this->contact = $user;
    }
```

en la ruta

```
Route::get('registeractivity/detail/{user}', [RegisteractivityController::class, 'detail'])->name('registeractivity.detail')->middleware('translate');
```

y obtengo lo siguiente

```
{"profile_photo_url":"https:\/\/ui-avatars.com\/api\/?name=&color=FFF&background=02555d"}
```

Realice un dd

```
App\Models\User {#14 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #hidden: array:4 [▼
    0 => "password"
    1 => "remember_token"
    2 => "two_factor_recovery_codes"
    3 => "two_factor_secret"
  ]
  #casts: array:1 [▼
    "email_verified_at" => "datetime"
  ]
  #appends: array:1 [▼
    0 => "profile_photo_url"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
  #accessToken: null
}
```

a pesar que la url coloque /registeractivity/detail/1 o 2  otros me sale el mismo resultado.

Comment: No estoy muy familiarizado del todo con **livewire** pero tu problema parece venir a la hora de obtener el parámetro `$deal` y se puede deber a lo siguiente: Estas llamando a un método especifico en la ruta `detail`; pero intentas obtener el parámetro en el **gancho de montaje** `mount($deal)`. Y creo que deberías obtenerlo en ese **método**, ejemplo `detail($deal)`. Segundo puede ser simplemente el valor de este parametro el que te esta dando problemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera

al principio intente pasar `{id}` pero me dice que este es un parámetro reservado

```
Route::get('registeractivity/detail/{id}', [RegisteractivityController::class, 'detail'])->name('registeractivity.detail')->middleware('translate');
```

en ton cambia por `{detailid}`

```
Route::get('/registeractivity/detail/{detailid}', DetailRegisteractivities::class)->name('registeractivity.detail')->middleware('translate');
```

lo otro que hice fue cambia el modo de llamar el controlador y esta vez llame directamente el controlador de Livewire en la vista **Web**

lo tenia así

```
use App\Http\Controllers\registeractivity\RegisteractivityController;

Route::get('registeractivity/detail', [RegisteractivityController::class, 'detail'])->name('registeractivity.detail')->middleware('translate');
```

La cual cambie por este

```
use App\Http\Livewire\Registeractivity\DetailRegisteractivities;

Route::get('/registeractivity/detail/{detailid}', DetailRegisteractivities::class)->name('registeractivity.detail')->middleware('translate');
```

y finalmente en el controlador coloque lo siguiente

```
public $detailid;

    public function mount($detailid)
    { 
      $this->detailid=$detailid;
    }
```

y ya desde el render u otra funcion llamo a `$this->detailid`

```
public function render()
    {
        $this->detailid = .....
        return view........
    }
```

Finalmente desde la vista principal llamo esta vista de la siguiente manera

```
<a href="{{ route('registeractivity.detail',$item->id) }}">Link</a>
```